# Sub query vs joins performance

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure-sql-database

I have two tables Sites and ScannedItems. Sites has around 15000 rows, and ScannedItems around 60 millions rows. Below query takes around 6 minutes with indexes on CountUniqueRoleAssignments, Modified and siteid. Can this in any way be optimized? Is some kind of join faster than sub queries or any other hints?

```
select 
    *,
    (select COUNT(*) from ScannedItems where ScannedItems.siteid=sites.siteid and ScannedItems.CountUniqueRoleAssignments>0) as CountUniquePermissions,
    (select COUNT(*) from ScannedItems where ScannedItems.siteid=sites.siteid and ScannedItems.Modified<DATEADD (day, -30 ,GETDATE())) as CountNotModified30Days
from sites
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would probably write this query using joins:

```sql
SELECT
    s.siteid,
    COALESCE(si.CountUniquePermissions, 0) AS CountUniquePermissions,
    COALESCE(si.CountNotModified30Days, 0) AS CountNotModified30Days
FROM sites s
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT siteid,
           COUNT(CASE WHEN CountUniqueRoleAssignments > 0 THEN 1 END)
               AS CountUniquePermissions,
           COUNT(CASE WHEN Modified < DATEADD (day, -30, GETDATE()) THEN 1 END)
               AS CountNotModified30Days
    FROM ScannedItems
    GROUP BY siteid
) si
    ON si.siteid = s.siteid
ORDER BY
    s.siteid;
```

The above query has no `WHERE` or `HAVING` clauses, and so I don't see any obvious way to tune it further using indices.  But it at least has the potential advantage over your current query that it doesn't involve `N^2` behavior with correlated subqueries in the select clause.

Comment: Just tested it MUCH faster. 36 secs. Thanks alot!

Comment: @ThomasSegato Great news!  Note that you may be able to simplify to the Popeye answer **if** you really only want to select the `siteid` column from the `sites` table.  If you want _other_ columns as well, then stick with my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `LEFT JOIN` and conditional aggregation as follows:

```
select 
    S.siteid,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN SI.CountUniqueRoleAssignments > 0 THEN 1 END) as CountUniquePermissions,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN SI.Modified<DATEADD (day, -30 ,GETDATE()) THEN 1 END ) as CountNotModified30Days
from sites S
LEFT JOIN ScannedItems SI ON SI.siteid = S.siteid
GROUP BY S.SITEID
```

Answer (score 0):

For any performance question, you should test the SQL code on your data.  For this query:

```
select s.*,
       (select COUNT(*)
        from ScannedItems si
        where si.siteid = s.siteid and si.CountUniqueRoleAssignments > 0
       ) as CountUniquePermissions,
       (select COUNT(*)
        from ScannedItems si
        where si.siteid = s.siteid and si.Modified < DATEADD(day, -30 ,GETDATE())
       ) as CountNotModified30Days
from sites s;
```

I would recommend two indexes:

- `ScannedItems(siteid, CountUniqueRoleAssignments)`
- `ScannedItems(siteid, Modified)`.

With these two indexes, I would expect this to be faster than any alternative that uses aggregation.  Why?  Aggregation is a rather expensive operation.  The correlated subqueries can use only the indexes for processing.

This is scanning two indexes (as compared to a single aggregation), so whether this is faster is not 100% guaranteed -- which is why you should test it.  However, if you have a filter on the `sites` table, the correlated subquery approach is often much faster, because only the sites returned by the query are used for the calculation.